# How to redefine a command to keep track of page assignments w/o exceeding TeX capacity

Tags: macros, lua, count, capacity

Seemed straight-forward enough (and I've changed it per Christian's suggestion of using `\edef` instead and added some status code):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\tabloidpagecount}{}
\newcommand{\shelftagpagecount}{}
\newcommand{\totalpagecount}{}
\newcounter{Tp}{}

\newcommand{\incTpc}{
\edef\Tpc{\tabloidpagecount}%
\edef\PC{\totalpagecount}%
\setcounter{Tp}{\thepage}
\addtocounter{Tp}{-1}
\renewcommand{\tabloidpagecount}{\Tpc\ \theTp}
\renewcommand{\totalpagecount}{\PC\ \theTp}
}

\newcommand{\incSTpc}{
\edef\STpc{\shelftagpagecount}%
\edef\PC{\totalpagecount}%
\setcounter{Tp}{\thepage}
\addtocounter{Tp}{-1}
\renewcommand{\shelftagpagecount}{\STpc\ \theTp}
\renewcommand{\totalpagecount}{\PC\ \theTp}
}

\newcommand{\outputstatus}{\par
TPC = \totalpagecount\par
tabloid = \tabloidpagecount\par
shelftags = \shelftagpagecount
\clearpage}

\begin{document}

a tabloidpage \incTpc\outputstatus

a standardpage \incSTpc\outputstatus

2nd standardpage \incSTpc\outputstatus

\outputstatus

\end{document}
```

It was failing on the 3rd page but Christian got me squared away on that w/ his suggestion of using `\edef`.

I'm using `lualatex`. Is there some way that I could do this in `Lua`? I need to write everything out to a file at the end if that matters.

I need to keep track of:

- total instances of pages (so for this it should be `0 1 2` which is working)
- total number of tabloid pages and which page(s) are tabloid (this should be `0` but for some reason is instead `2` at the end)
- total number of shelftag pages and which they are `1 2` (which is also working)

Comment: you have defined an infinite loop so it would use up any finite amount of space `\PC` is defined to expand to `\PC` ad infinitum. But it is not enough just to show non-working code you need to say what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks! Christian got me on the correct track, and I've got a working test file now. Next I just have to get both page types working in my production file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view you want `\edef\PC{\totalpagecount}` etc, i.e. expansion of the current content, not a recursive definition of `\totalpagecount` by `\let` etc.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\tabloidpagecount}{}
\newcommand{\shelftagpagecount}{}
\newcommand{\totalpagecount}{}
\newcounter{Tp}{}

\newcommand{\incTpc}{%
\edef\Tpc{\tabloidpagecount}%
\edef\PC{\totalpagecount}%
\setcounter{Tp}{\value{page}}%
\addtocounter{Tp}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\tabloidpagecount}{\Tpc\ \theTp}
\renewcommand{\totalpagecount}{\PC\ \theTp}
}

\newcommand{\incSTpc}{%
\edef\Tpc{\shelftagpagecount}%
\edef\PC{\totalpagecount}%
\setcounter{Tp}{\value{page}}%
\addtocounter{Tp}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\shelftagpagecount}{\Tpc\ \theTp}
\renewcommand{\totalpagecount}{\PC\ \theTp}
}

\begin{document}

a tabloidpage \incTpc\clearpage

a standardpage \incSTpc\clearpage

2nd standardpage \incSTpc\clearpage

TPC = \totalpagecount\par
tabloid = \tabloidpagecount\par
shelftags = \shelftagpagecount

\end{document}
```

Comment: That almost works. It works for the total and standard pages, but for some reason, the tabloid pages equals the last page --- not sure how / why it's getting touched / updated / changed after it's set initially.

Comment: WillAdams: I am unsure what you want to achieve at all

Comment: As I noted, I'm trying to keep track of which pages have been assigned to what size. I believe th e problem is that \tabloidpagecount contains a macro which isn't expanded, so it changes to match the current page if it was only called once.

Comment: and the solution is to use \edef more:

Comment: @WillAdams: At the time of posting my answer, the purpose of your request wasn't clear, so I kept it using one `\edef`.